# My controllers doesnt work for any pages other than home.html in Ionic3. I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, controller, ionic3

this is my index.html (www/index.html)

```
<body  ng-app = 'myApp'>
 <ion-app></ion-app>

<!--   EXTERNALN JS FILES   -->
<script src = 'build/js/script.js'></script>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

this is my app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { ViewPage } from '../pages/view/view';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {tabsPlacement: 'top'})
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

and here's my contacts.html

```
<ion-content padding ng-controller = 'contactCtrl'>
```

Conatcts

```
<ion-content>
<p ng-bind = 'text'></p>
</ion-content>
```

also script.js

```
 var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
//controller in contact
myApp.controller('contactCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.text = 'ctrl 2';
});
//controller in home
myApp.controller('controllerOne', function($scope){
    $scope.text = 'ctrl 2';
});
```

The controllerOne works but contactCtrl doesnt load at all.The controller seems to be working only for the page home. while the controller doesn't even load for other pages.
I am using
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.6
Angular Core: 5.0.3
Node: 8.9.3
Os Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: ionic 2+ uses [angular](https://angular.io/) not [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/). You are mixing them

Answer (score 0):

you have mixed the ionic 1 and ionic 2. i suggest you to learn ionic 2.